# Regular Expression 7 digits-2digits

Tags: regex

I'm using ASP.net C# and I have a text box which I want to validate so the user can only input 7 digits followed by a - (dash) followed by 2 digits.

Example:
    1111111-11
    1234567-89

What would the regular expression be to only allow this format. This will be very simple for someone.

Thanks ion advance.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @HamZa I'm wondering - why didn't you downvote? This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @JanDvorak I hate downvoting. If you take a look at my vote casts, it's quite low. Well, I know it's kind of "bad" to not downvote the bad questions/answers ...

Comment: I had researched and found solutions to just 7 digits and more simple expressions but could not find out how to add 2 together with a - in between. Just because I havnt presented my research it automaticaly means I didn't do any. Wow.

Comment: @Safinn I don't have magic powers to see what you've tried/researched. So please show the efforts in your question. That way, we could also correct you where you went wrong. See, this is a learning process. Also if you found out how to match 7 digits, it would be quite easy to find out how to match 2 digits, and then it's just a matter of "logic" to combine the 2 by adding `-` between them. It's important to get the idea behind the solution and completely understand it. Now you've got the solution and who knows you don't even grasp it ?

Comment: Yes I now understand it. I didn't think it was a simple as just putting the 2 expressions next to each other like that. I thought you might of had to have like a '+' or '&' between them to link them which is why I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with ASP.net but the regular expression should look something like

```
^[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{2}$
```

or

```
^\d{7}-\d{2}$
```

if the `\d` class is usable.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
 ^[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{2}$
```