# Find files in folder which have x digits

Tags: regex, shell, grep

Hello have to fix some file names for taking them into further consideration. 
Let's assume i only what to list the files which have 7 digits in the beginning of the file name. 
For example

```
8795811-005-2535.txt
8-002-2535.txt
8795814-003-2535.txt
8795511-003-2535.txt
8798-005-2535.txt
```

what i would love to get is

```
8795811-005-2535.txt
8795814-003-2535.txt
8795511-003-2535.txt
```

Since it starts with 7 occurences of [0-9]
How do i archive this with

```
 ls | grep '[0-9]'
```

How do i get the 7 occurences into the regular expression ?

Searching for hours for a practical tutorial or example...

Comment: `ls | grep '[0-9]{7}'`

Comment: \d{7} or [0-9]{7}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression 7 digits-2digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765611/regular-expression-7-digits-2digits)

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep -E "^[0-9]{7}.*"
```

-E gives you access to extended regex options

Regex breakdown:

```
^
```

Find the start of the string,

```
[0-9]{7}
```

then match 7 digits,

```
.*
```

followed by anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the suggestions..

```
8795811-005-2535.txt
ls | grep -E "[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}.txt"
```

did make my day..defiantly have to learn more about regec..pretty cool.

Answer (score -1):

```
for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
```

or

```
ls [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching